# Thread synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I have one thread that locks a mutex, writes a value to a variable, unlocks the mutex. 
I do a print out here and the value has been changed. I set it to 1.

When I read the variables value in another thread using lock, unlock on the mutex and read the value, I get the old value of 0.

Why is this happening. I lock and unlock the same mutex correctly.

How do I sync threads?

EDIT:

I declare the mutexes and variables here

```
static pthread_mutex_t movementIdMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int nav_movementId = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t newMovementMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int nav_newMovement = 0;
```

I set the variables here

```
void nav_setMovementIdentifier(int id)
{
printf("Received movement id:%d from connectivity\n", id);

int result; /* Use the result for testing */

result = pthread_mutex_lock(&movementIdMutex);
nav_movementId = id;
printf("nav_movementId is %d\n", nav_movementId);
result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&movementIdMutex);

result = pthread_mutex_lock(&newMovementMutex);
nav_newMovement = 1;
printf("nav_newMovement is %d in the setId function\n", nav_newMovement);
result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&newMovementMutex);
printf("\n");
}
```

and read them here

```
void *startConnectivityListener(void *ptr)     {

/* Declare safety variables because segments cant be locked/unlocked 
*  using mutexes if they are checking in statement such as if and while.
*/
int newMoveCheck = 0;
int startIndoorCheck = 0;
int startOutdoorCheck = 0;

int listening = 1;

while(listening == 1)
{
    int result; /* Use for testing */

    /* check if a new movement command waits */
    result = pthread_mutex_lock(&newMovementMutex);
    newMoveCheck = nav_newMovement;
    printf("nav new movement in thread is :%d\n", nav_newMovement);
    printf("newMoveCheck in mutex lock is:%d\n", newMoveCheck);
    result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&newMovementMutex);

    result = pthread_mutex_lock(&movementIdMutex);
    printf("nav_movementId in thread is %d\n", nav_movementId);
    result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&movementIdMutex);

    printf("newMoveCheck is %d\n", newMoveCheck);
    sleep(1);

    if(newMoveCheck == 1)
```

I get the correct print outs in the setter functions printf statements, it set the values to id that is passed in and to 1.

When I try print it where I read them, both are still showing 0, which is what they were set to when I initialized them.

Comment: Need to see some code so we can tell where the issue might be

Comment: can you provide a compilable example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I added the relevant code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `volatile` specifier to `nav_movementId` and `nav_newMovement` variables.

Comment: The issue in the end was that the processes themselves were forked so their were 2 copes of the programs running in their own processes and the one was updating its own variables and the other was reading its own, non updated, variables. When printing the memory addresses they were the same based on the virtual memory address that was created before the processes were forked. weird setup :P

Answer (score 0):

These declarations:

```
static int nav_movementId = 0;
static int nav_newMovement = 0;
```

create entirely new and different variables - that's why you don't see the modifications to the global variable.  Make the declaration like so so the function that's updating the variables is acting on the global instances:

```
extern int nav_movementId;
extern int nav_newMovement;
```

Similarly, the mutexes need to be the same instances - they need to be globals or you need to arrange to get their addresses shared between the modules.

In one module:

```
pthread_mutex_t movementIdMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t newMovementMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

In a header (or the other module):

```
extern pthread_mutex_t movementIdMutex;
extern pthread_mutex_t newMovementMutex;
```

Comment: The variables and mutexes are declared in the .c file and all the thread code is in the same file. So in theory the variables should be available for all the threads. would the static mutex variables be different copies too? What should be done? Should I remove the static declarations of the mutexes and variables?

Comment: What if code is run in its own process and it includes the .h file or corelogic.c which is part of another process. I have one process running a bunch of code that includes the header of a module that is running in another process. What is the code in process 1 calls the code in process 2 and sets variables that are present in code that is in process2? Does process 1 have a copy of all the code connected via the .h file  that it includes from process 2's modules? So there is 2 copies of the variables, 1 for each process? Is it impossible to set process 2's variables from process 1?

Comment: If you are saying that "corelogic.c" is included into more than one executable image and/or you are running more than one copy of the same executable then the answer is: There is one copy of the variables for each running process.  You can't share memory between processes simply by declaring the same variable in each one.

Comment: We are using shared memory on linux(ubuntu), but what happens if process 1 includes a .h file just for calling functions from it. And the .h file and the rest of the code for this second subsystem is running in process 2.

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't realize that all this code was in the same module - my answer doesn't make sense in that scenario.  I also didn't realize that the mutexes and variables were being shared between processes.  I'm not experienced with that use - all I know is that you'll need to initialize the mutexes with attributes indicating that they're being shared by separate processes.  I don't know if the the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` default is adequate.  You may need to set the mutex attribute to `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` using `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are those static mutexes and variables in the same source file as the code below, or are they in a header?  If they are in a header and those two functions are in separate files, then each one has it's own copy of the mutex and variable.  You need to make them `extern` instead of `static.`

Another thing:  The "listener" function is not actually waiting for the variables to be set by the other function - the mutex is only ensuring that they are not being actively written to.   So I wouldn't be suprised if the first time you read `nav_newMovement` in the listener that it is still 0.     A little more explanation of how you expect the system to works might help here.

Comment: The way the system should work is that a module corelogic.c has all the variables, mutexes, thread code in it. Other modules import the header file so that they can use the functions for setting the variables values. I have a few threads that are started and one of them reads the values of the variables that are set from a function call that I mentioned. The issue is that the variables are updating when they are being set, but are not showing the updated values when reading. I suspect that there are 2 sets of these variables or something, 2 copies.

Comment: Note that printf is buffered and not exactly thread safe.  You may not get the printouts in the exact order they occurred.  Is the reader in a loop? - it looks like it, but the code is not complete.  If the writer is not called until some time after the reader loop is started, I'd expect to see several "newMoveCheck is 0" before a you see a "1".  If this is test code exiting on the first "1" you may never see the final printf at all.

Comment: Please see my second comment on Michael's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thread execution order is indeterminant, meaning just because you've launched a thread doesn't mean that the execution order of the threads will be in the order you've launched them.  In order to sync threads then, you have to create "barriers", that is a point in the code where one thread cannot continue until another thread has reached a specific point.  This is typically done with semaphores, although you can do it with mutexes and condition variables.

The concept is that if you had two threads, and two semaphores, you can cause one thread to block while the other thread is running.  Then when the first thread is done running, it unblocks the second thread, and the second thread blocks the first thread.  This can keep repeating where one thread blocks while the other thread works and vice versa.  So the steps would be:

1. Thread #1 initializes semaphore #1 as locked, and semaphore #2 as unlocked
2. Thread #1 launches Thread #2, which then locks semaphore #2 and continues on
3. Meanwhile Thread #1 tries to lock the already locked semaphore #1, so it sits blocked while Thread #2 works
4. Thread #2 is finished and unlocks semaphore #1 ... Thread #1 now continues on
5. Thread #2 tries to lock semaphore #2, but it's locked, so it must wait for Thread #1 to finish working
6. Thread #1 finishes working and unlocks semaphore #2 ... Thread #2 now continues
7. Thread #1 tries to lock semaphore #1, but it's locked, so it must wait for Thread #2 to finish working
8. Keep repeating until you reach some finishing condition ...

So basically Thread #1 unlocks Thread #2, and vice versa.  Thread #1 does not unlock itself and then lock Thread #2, or some other variation where a single thread has to both lock and unlock a semaphore for itself and another thread.  That way you don't end up with a "cross-over" point where neither thread is locked and their both running free, or worse, a dead-lock condition where both threads are waiting for the other thread to unlock themselves.

By using semaphores, you can effectively create "barriers" in your application that will allow for some level of determinism in the way threads are run, and create threads that are synchronized to each other.  You will be able to deterministically say that a thread cannot continue past a certain point until another thread has reached a certain point ... hence your synchronization points are created using the inherent nature of a semaphore.